# Styles Don't apply to react bootstrap nav bar

Tags: css, react-bootstrap

I'm trying to design a responsive NavBar  in a react project but the styles do not apply to it. Am I missing some imports? this is a simple question but its lagging my work

```
import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css'
<nav className='navbar navbar-default'>
     <div class='navbar-header'>
          <img src={pic} className='pic' />
     </div>
     <ul className='nav navbar-nav'>
          <li><Link to='/' style={{ textDecoration: 'none', color: '#5B5454', fontSize: '20px' }}>Home</Link></li>
          <li><Link to='/src/Header/Problem.js' style={{ textDecoration: 'none', color: '#5B5454', fontSize: '20px' }} >Problem</Link></li>
     <ul/>
<nav/>
```

```css
.nav navbar-nav
{
        list-style-type: none;
        margin: 0px;
        float: right;
        position: relative;
        right: 20px;
        top: 85px; 
        left: 10px;
        padding: 10px;
        width: 83%; 
}
.nav navbar-nav li
{
      position: relative;
      margin-left:30px;
      right:10px;
      display: inline-block;
      font-family: 'Ubuntu',sans-serif;
}
```

Comment: you should add .navbar-nav. you missed that dot [    .   ]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

both of nav and navbar-nav are classes that given to a div so that you should use below CSS code:

```
.nav.navbar-nav
{
        list-style-type: none;
        margin: 0px;
        float: right;
        position: relative;
        right: 20px;
        top: 85px; 
        left: 10px;
        padding: 10px;
        width: 83%; 
}
.nav.navbar-nav li
{
      position: relative;
      margin-left:30px;
      right:10px;
      display: inline-block;
      font-family: 'Ubuntu',sans-serif;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

try like this

**HTML**

```
import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css'
<nav className='navbar navbar-default'>
     <div class='navbar-header'>
          <img src={pic} className='pic' />
     </div>
     <ul className='nav navbar-nav'>
          <li><Link to='/' style={{ textDecoration: 'none', color: '#5B5454', fontSize: '20px' }}>Home</Link></li>
          <li><Link to='/src/Header/Problem.js' style={{ textDecoration: 'none', color: '#5B5454', fontSize: '20px' }} >Problem</Link></li>
     <ul/>
<nav/>
```

**css**

```
nav ul
{
        list-style-type: none;
        margin: 0px;
        float: right;
        position: relative;
        right: 20px;
        top: 85px; 
        left: 10px;
        padding: 10px;
        width: 83%; 
}
nav ul li
{
      position: relative;
      margin-left:30px;
      right:10px;
      display: inline-block;
      font-family: 'Ubuntu',sans-serif;
}
```

Comment: please check now i changed code now.. do need responsive means add media quries.

Answer (score 0):

```
Firstly you should install bootstrap npm then include the index.js page. if you import bootstrap in the index.jsx page.All components `enter code here` got style



import  'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css'; in the index.js page

npm install: npm i bootstrap@versionname or npm i bootstrap
```